# Why use a new call with a C++ 'vector'?

Tags: c++, vector, new-operator

The code `vector<someType> myVector;` dynamically allocates memory, so any elements stored will live until a `delete` is called. So how is the following, `vector<someType> *myVector = new vector<someType>();`, different (other than being a pointer) from the earlier one?

Is there a double allocation happening here?
Everyone mentions it is evil to mix a `vector` with a `new` call, but why? If it is evil, why is it acceptable code for the compiler and when is it okay to use?

Comment: bad practice does not mean something should be illegal

Comment: It's evil in the sense that you shouldn't really need a pointer if you have access to `vector`s. There is nothing syntactically _wrong_ with it. There _is_ a double allocation. One for the vector itself (through the pointer), and one for its elements. You manage the first, the class manages the latter.

Comment: The first one calls delete for you, the second one lets you forget and create memory leaks. There is no point in having a pointer to a vector because the vector does the pointer stuff for you on the inside where it belongs.

Comment: Because you want the vector pointed to by `myVector` to live beyond it's local scope.  `myVector` might be better as a smart pointer, it might not; your question does not include enough context to make any concrete recommendation.

Comment: @RichardCritten These days you can simply use `std::move` or `return` to pass the vector out of the scope.

Comment: _so any elements stored will live until a delete is called_ Until vector goes out of scope

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your first statement is not true. The elements in `vector<someType> myVector` will live until the vector is destroyed. If `vector<someType>` is a local variable, it will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope. You don't need to call delete explicitly. Calling `delete` explicitly is error-prone if you take into account that because of exceptions that might be thrown, your `delete` statement may never be reached, leading to memory leaks.
E.g. compare the following two cases

```
void foo()
{
   std::vector<int> v;
   v.push_back(1);
   f(); // f is some operation that might throw exception.
}  // v is automatically destroyed even if f throws.

void bar()
{
   std::vector<int>* v = new std::vector<int>;
   v->push_back(1);
   f(); // f is some operation that might throw exception.
   delete v;  // You need to call delete explicitly here.
              // The vector will be destroyed only if f doesn't throw.
}
```

Apart from the above, it's true that a vector dynamically allocates memory to store new elements. The difference between the two cases is:

- `std::vector<int> v`    v is an object on the stack, that dynamically allocates memory in order to store elements.
- `std::vector<int>* v = new std::vector<int>`   v is a pointer to a dynamically allocated object, that dynamically allocates memory in order to store elements. As said already, you need to explictly call delete to destroy this object.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning `std::unique_ptr< std::vector<int> >` as an alternative when dynamic allocation is required.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a double allocation happening here?

Depends on what you mean by "double allocation".

You are allocating memory for the `std::vector` using dynamic memory allocation. The constructor of `std::vector` does the same thing for the elements of the `std::vector`. If that is what you mean by "double allocation", then the answer is "Yes".

> Everyone mentions it is evil to mix a vector with a new call, but why?

Use of

```
vector<someType> *myVector = new vector<someType>();
```

implies that you are taking responsibility of managing dynamically allocated memory for `myVector`. That introduces some pitfalls:

1. `new vector<someType>()` can throw `std::bad_alloc`. You'll have to add code to deal with the exception. If you don't, you will end up terminating your application.
2. You have to make sure that you deallocate the memory. If you don't, your program leaks memory.
3. You have to make sure that you don't use the pointer after the memory has been deallocated.

These are not exactly *evil* but you add more work in your application code than is necessary.

> If it is evil, why is it acceptable code for the compiler and when is it okay to use?

If you have an application where you are managing low level data in some core components for reasons that make sense to you, it's acceptable to use dynamically allocated `std::vector`. I think it's unacceptable to have such code strewn all over your code base. That's my opinion, obviously. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

> The code `vector<someType> myVector;` dynamically allocates memory, so any elements stored will live until a delete is called

No. This memory will be deleted when this object is no more available.

Consider the following:

```
{
    // Allocate a vector of 4 ints
    vector<int> v(4);

    // Do a lot of operations on this vector

}
```

After this scope ends, `v` will be deleted (RAII). So the memory allocated by it is automatically freed.

But

```
{
    // Allocate a vector of 4 ints
    vector<int> *v = new vector<int>(4);

    // Do a lot of operations on this vector

}
```

After this scope ends, the `v` object isn't deleted, until you call `delete v` explicitly.

For a better approach than pointers to make your object escape the scope, is to use `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, and `weak_ptr`, this will keep you safe from forgetting using `delete`

Comment: How will smart pointers help the vector "escape the scope"? - Won't the smart pointer itself go out of scope, hence making the vector go out of scope? (Meaning you should clarify that you can't just stick a smart pointer between the braces. Smart pointers are there so you don't have to manage memory allocated on the heap yourself).

Comment: You should not need pointers to pass the vector out of the scope. You can use `std::move` or just `return` the vector and its contents will be moved (not copied).

Comment: But if you want to "share" the vector between more than one object without performance issues?, you should use "shared_ptr".   `std::move` is a good idea, returning the vector also will move the value not copy, but this is indirectly due to something called "copy elision"  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Good point. I meant to return a "shared_ptr<vector<T> >"/"unique_ptr<<vector<T> > " from a function for example. But `std::move` or "copy elision" may be better